# How compress int (number) in Go

Tags: go

is there any way to compress int and decompress it use Go?

For example this number 10 char `4251658154`

I want to compress (make size small, for example my 10 char int to 5 char bytes) int or any kind of data type accept number than decompress it

Comment: Please clarify your question. Compression of a single int will not yield any benefit, compression algorithms take advantage of repeated or sparse data to save bytes but need extra information to decompress. Furthermore, the interface to compression algorithms is usually sets of bytes (in Go: io.Reader and io.Writer interfaces).

Comment: How about you store the int as an int, not as a string? You’ll hardly get any more compact than that.

Comment: That is not how numbers work in computers. 4251658154 fits into uint32, which is only 4 bytes to begin with, not 10. That being said, there are some encodings that *can* save space, such as [varint](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints) (see [the encoding/binary package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#pkg-index)).

Comment: @Peter: To be clear, such encodings can save space _sometimes_. In other cases, they actually [increase](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#pkg-constants) the size requirements.

Comment: Is there a reason you're talking about the text representation of a number, rather than it's in-memory binary representation? If you must convey your number via a text channel (such as email), then you can use hexidecimal, or base64, or even possibly base96, for more compact representations.

Comment: "[I]s there any way to compress int and decompress it use Go?" Yes, especially if you do not insist of the a compress-decompress-cycle to be lossless: Just encode any number to 0x00 and decode 0x00 to 0x00 always. You _really_ _must_ clarify your question.

Comment: @Volker my mean from encode is decrees size of characters. For example 10 length int to 5 length bytes

Comment: As now observed in comments below, you're apparently dealing with IP addresses. IP addresses (for IPv4) are _always_ exactly 4 bytes. Just use the natural representation, and you'll save space. No compression necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to compress arbitrary number at different magniturdes, What you're looking for is varint encoding. If the number is small (<127) it can be encoded in one byte, and so forth. Example [from the docs:](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#PutVarint)

package main

```
import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    buf := make([]byte, binary.MaxVarintLen64)

    for _, x := range []int64{-65, -64, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 63, 64} {
        n := binary.PutVarint(buf, x)
        fmt.Printf("%x\n", buf[:n])
    }
}

// Prints:
// 8101
// 7f
// 03
// 01
// 00
// 02
// 04
// 7e
// 8001
```

If however you want to represent IPV4 addresses in an efficient manner, just encode them as unsigned int32 numbers.

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func IPToNumber(addr string) (uint32, error) {
    var n uint32
    err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(net.ParseIP(addr).To4()), binary.BigEndian, &n)
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    if n, err := IPToNumber("255.255.255.255"); err == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%x", n)
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP's example, `4251658154`, isn't very small. It's varint encoding is `d49ed9d61f` using your above code, and  requiring 5 bytes.

Comment: OP Actually says "for example my 10 char int to 5 char bytes". It beats representing the number as int64 or string.

Comment: Pretty much anything practical will beat base 10, of course. The point Flimzy wanted to make is that the varint in this particular case is bigger than the natural representation of uint32, which is well worth pointing out.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194363/discussion-on-answer-by-not-a-golfer-how-compress-int-number-in-go).